# I am having trouble getting my program to display the average in ascending order

Tags: java, sorting

Im trying to make a program that reads integers, lists them in ascending order, outputs them into a file called sorted.txt, calculates the average, and displays the average and total numbers. I was able to get pretty much all of the program correct, except the part where I put the file in ascending order.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
      Scanner inputFile=null;
      try {
          inputFile = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND");
          return;
      }
      int n;
      int index=1;
      ArrayList<Integer>list = new ArrayList<>();
      Collections.sort(list);
      double total = 0, avg;
      while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
          n = inputFile.nextInt();
          list.add(n);
          total += n;
      }
      //Here is where I have trouble
      //I am able to get it to run if I delete these lines up to...
      {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++) {
          if (num[i] > num[j])
          {
            temp = num[i];
            num[i] = num[j];
            num[j] = temp;
            }
          }
        }
        //These lines. The rest works fine. 
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("sorted.txt"));
      for(Integer i:list)
          pw.println(i);
      pw.close();
      inputFile.close();
      avg = total / list.size();
      System.out.printf("The Total of " +index+" numbers in file %.2f\n",total);
      System.out.printf("The Average of " +index+" numbers in file %.2f",avg);
  }
}
```

If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for any and all input! I am fairly new to programing and am trying to teach myself.

Comment: All the variables under this section are undefined in the first place, hence there will be a compilation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the line of sorting while and remove the for

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

```
 Scanner inputFile=null;
      try {
          inputFile = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND");
          return;
      }
      int n;
      int index=1;
      List<Integer>list = new ArrayList<>();
      double total = 0, avg;
      while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
          n = inputFile.nextInt();
          list.add(n);
          total += n;
      }

      Collections.sort(list);
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("sorted.txt"));
      for(Integer i:list)
          pw.println(i);
      pw.close();
      inputFile.close();
      avg = total / list.size();
      System.out.printf("The Total of " +index+" numbers in file %.2f\n",total);
      System.out.printf("The Average of " +index+" numbers in file %.2f",avg);
```